# Unwind Segue to re load updated Table View Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have Table View that has an "Add' button and you click on the add button and a new View Controller modally opens and you input the text fields (name, position, rating, etc...) and when you click save it takes you to the player profile page which contains all of the information you entered in the "Add View Controller." I also have a Unwind Segue on the player profile page to get you back to the table view that lists all of the players you added. My issue is when I click on the button that unwinds back to the table view, it does not add the new player. IE If I have 3 players in my table view to start, I click add to add the fourth, enter the info and hit save and am taken to the player profile page and when I hit the unwind button the table view still lists 3, not 4. Below is my Unwind code...

```
@IBAction func unwindToRecipeList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? RecipeDetailViewController, recipe = sourceViewController.recipe {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            recipes[selectedIndexPath.row] = recipe
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: recipes.count, inSection: 0)
            recipes.append(recipe)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` after you append recipe to recipes:

```
    @IBAction func unwindToRecipeList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? RecipeDetailViewController, recipe = sourceViewController.recipe {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            recipes[selectedIndexPath.row] = recipe
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {

            recipes.append(recipe)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: recipes.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do I have to pass the data back to my table view a different way?

Comment: are you correctly getting recipe from your sourceviewcontroller?, can you print it inside your else statement?, then print recipes after appending the recipe.